# Access to the new column name from the function inside across

Tags: r, dplyr, across

Is it possible to get the name of the new column from the `across` function?

For example

```
data.frame(a=1) %>% 
mutate(across(c(b=a, c=a), function(i) if("new column name"=="b") a+1 else a+0.5))
```

Expected result:

```r
#>   a b   c
#> 1 1 2 1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I attempted to use `cur_column()` but its return value appears to be `a` in this case.

I apologise that this example is too simple to achieve the desired result in other ways, but my actual code is a large nested dataframe that is difficult to provide.

Comment: What is `c(b=a, c=a)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @tmfmnk I want to create two new columns using column `a`. Of course I can create them individually like `mutate(b=function(a), c=function(a))` but it's redundant, so I was wondering if I could create them with less codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. It seems that because you are defining `b` and `c` within the `across` call, they aren't available through `cur_column()`.

```r
data.frame(a=1) %>%
  mutate(across(c(b=a, c=a), function(i) print(cur_column())))
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] "a"
```

It works fine if they are already defined in the `data.frame`. Using `tibble()` here so I can refer to `a` in the constructor.

```r
tibble(a=1, b=a, c=a) %>%
  mutate(across(-a, ~ if (cur_column() == "b") .x + 1 else .x + 0.5))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2   1.5
```

And similarly works even if you are in the same `mutate()` call, just making sure to define `b` and `c` prior to `across()`.

```r
data.frame(a=1) %>%
  mutate(across(c(b=a, c=a), ~.x),
         across(-a, ~ if (cur_column() == "b") .x + 1 else .x + 0.5))
#>   a b   c
#> 1 1 2 1.5
```

I believe it's happening because `across` is working across the `rhs` (`a`) and assigning the values to the `lhs` (`b`) only after the function in `across()` has been applied. I'm not sure this is the expected behavior (although it does seem right), I actually don't know, so will open up a GitHub issue because I think it's an interesting example!

Comment: Thank you for your kind quick response. If there's no other way, then I will create the new columns first and change their values afterward. Please let me wait for other potential comments.